# How to simulate mouse clicks in QML?

Tags: qt, events, onclick, mouse, qml

I'm trying to send a `QMouseEvent` to the QML objects being currently displayed.
The `QApplication::sendEvent()` always returns `false` meaning that my event did not get handled; but I don't see why.
Maybe I'm sending the event to the wrong object? Where should I send it to? 
I also played around with `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent` instead of `QMouseEvent` but had no luck either.

I tried stepping through the event code with the debugger but it is too complex for me to see why it's not working.

#### Background

I'm working on a piece of software that will be controlled via a simple touch screen. I get the touch events via ethernet and I want to synthesize mouse click events from them.
This way the software will be controlled on the target device in the same way as on a developer PC.

#### Update

1. As noted by fejd, the click code was executed before `QApplication::Exec()`, so I moved it into a timer handler that will be triggered while `exec()` is running.
2. Added Windows-specific code that works as expected.
3. Added some more attempts in Qt none of which works no matter whether `sendEvent()` returns `true` or `false`.

So far I have this:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "qmlapplicationviewer.h"

#include "clicksimulator.h"

#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QmlApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setOrientation(QmlApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qml/qmlClickSimulator/main.qml"));
    viewer.showMaximized();

    ClickSimulator sim(&viewer);
    QTimer timer;
    sim.connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(click()));
    timer.start(100);

    return app.exec();
}
```

#### clicksimulator.h

```
#ifndef CLICKSIMULATOR_H
#define CLICKSIMULATOR_H

#include <QObject>

class QmlApplicationViewer;

class ClickSimulator : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QmlApplicationViewer* m_viewer;
public:
    explicit ClickSimulator(QmlApplicationViewer* viewer, QObject *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void click();    
};

#endif // CLICKSIMULATOR_H
```

#### clicksimulator.cpp

```
#include "clicksimulator.h"
#include "qmlapplicationviewer.h"

#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QTest>

#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#define WINVER 0x0501
#include "Windows.h"


ClickSimulator::ClickSimulator(QmlApplicationViewer* viewer, QObject *parent) :
QObject(parent)
, m_viewer(viewer)
{
}

void ClickSimulator::click()
{
    if (NULL != m_viewer)
    {
        const int x = qrand() % 500 + 100, y = qrand() % 500 + 100;

        {
           QMouseEvent pressEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, QPoint(x, y), Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
//            QMouseEvent pressEvent(
//                QEvent::MouseButtonPress, 
//                QPoint(x, y),
//                Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
           const bool isSent = QApplication::sendEvent(m_viewer->scene(), &pressEvent);
           qDebug() << "'Press' at (" << x << "," << y << ") successful? " << isSent;
        }

        {
            QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent pressEvent(QEvent::GraphicsSceneMousePress);
            pressEvent.setScenePos(QPointF(x, y));
            pressEvent.setButton(Qt::LeftButton);
            pressEvent.setButtons(Qt::LeftButton);

            QGraphicsItem* item = m_viewer->itemAt(x, y);
            const bool isSent = m_viewer->scene()->sendEvent(item, &pressEvent);
            //const bool isSent = QApplication::sendEvent(m_viewer->scene(), &pressEvent);
            qDebug() << "'Press' at (" << x << "," << y << ") successful? " << isSent;
        }

        // This platform specific code works...
        {
            const double fScreenWidth = ::GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSCREEN )-1; 
            const double fScreenHeight = ::GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSCREEN )-1; 
            const double fx = x*(65535.0f/fScreenWidth);
            const double fy = y*(65535.0f/fScreenHeight);

            INPUT inp[3];
            inp[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;

            MOUSEINPUT & mi = inp[0].mi;
            mi.dx = fx;
            mi.dy = fy;
            mi.mouseData = 0;
            mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
            mi.time = 0;
            mi.dwExtraInfo = 0;

            inp[1] = inp[0];
            inp[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;

            inp[2] = inp[0];
            inp[2].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

            SendInput(3, inp, sizeof(INPUT));
        }
    }
}
```

#### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text {
        id: text1
        text: qsTr("This text is placed at the click coordinates")
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mousearea1
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
        console.log("click at " + mouse.x + ", " + mouse.y);
            text1.pos.x = mouse.x;
            text1.pos.y = mouse.y;
        }
    }
}
```

#### output

```
'Press' at ( 147 , 244 ) successful?  false 
'Press' at ( 147 , 244 ) successful?  true
```

Comment: Did you try the MouseEvent in which you specify globalPos too?

`The globalPos() is initialized to QCursor::pos(), which may not be appropriate. Use the other constructor to specify the global position explicitly.`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you send the event before app.exec(), I don't think the main event loop has been started . You could try [postEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent) instead, though that might fail as well if exec() clears the event queue before it starts. In that case, perhaps you can post it somewhere after exec()?

**Update:** Got it working now by looking at the [QDeclarativeMouseArea autotests](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/blobs/master/tests/auto/qtquick1/qdeclarativemousearea/tst_qdeclarativemousearea.cpp#line492). What was missing was the release event. This worked for me:

```
QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent pressEvent(QEvent::GraphicsSceneMousePress);
pressEvent.setScenePos(QPointF(x, y));
pressEvent.setButton(Qt::LeftButton);
pressEvent.setButtons(Qt::LeftButton);
QApplication::sendEvent(m_viewer->scene(), &pressEvent);

QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent releaseEvent(QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseRelease);
releaseEvent.setScenePos(QPointF(x, y));
releaseEvent.setButton(Qt::LeftButton);
releaseEvent.setButtons(Qt::LeftButton);
QApplication::sendEvent(m_viewer->scene(), &releaseEvent);
```

What was a bit odd was that onPressed in the QML file did not get called after the press event - only after the release event was sent as well.

Comment: Good point regarding `exec()`. Moving the code into a timer-handler did not work either, though. I updated the question with my current test code.

Comment: @foraidt I've updated the answer. Tested on a Mac though, hopefully the behavior is the same on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works, but there is a better way. Just use `QGraphicScene`'s

```
bool sendEvent(QGraphicsItem* item, QEvent* event)
```

function. If you know which item to send the event to.