# Simulate clicked QML element from QTest

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, signals, qml

I'm playing around with QTest and want simulate a mouse click in my test on one of my QML elements that I have in my UI. 
**So in other words I would like to trigger the onClicked signal handler in my QML code from C++?**

This is how my QML looks like:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle
{
    objectName: "MessageRectangle"
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text
    {
        objectName: "MessageText"
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        id: simplebutton
        objectName: "ChangeTextButton"
        color: "grey"
        width: 150; height: 75

        Text
        {
            id: buttonLabel
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "button label"
        }

        MouseArea
        {
            id: buttonMouseArea
            objectName: "ChangeTextButtonMouseArea"
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked:
            {
                CppApi.setMessage( "Button Clicked" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is a bit hard to show all the different solutions that I have tried. But I have tried to connect an own class derived from QObject with the QML item and sending click signal to it:

```
   QObject::connect( this, SIGNAL( clicked() ), pItem, SLOT( onClicked() ) );
   emit clicked();
```

I have also tried to call the following way:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod( pButton, "pressedChanged", Qt::DirectConnection );
```

Where pButton is the QQuickItem which I get when I grab the object named ChangeTextButtonMouseArea.

I have found some similar questions here. But there seems to be something different with the onClicked, somehow. If I print out all the methods that are defined in the QMetaObject that I get from the QQuickItem, then I can't find the onClicked function or the clicked signal.

This answer is somewhat in the correct direction but the the signal I want to send is not created by myself:
[C++ SIGNAL to QML SLOT in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834147/c-signal-to-qml-slot-in-qt)

I also found this question:
[How to simulate mouse clicks in QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517700/how-to-simulate-mouse-clicks-in-qml)
But I only want to trigger a click event on a specific QML object. Do I really need to calculate the coordinates of my mouse click? Doing that seems a bit complicated since the QML items are only aware of the relative positions to their parents.

Am I trying something that is not possible? Or is the reason that I can't find any answers on the internet because the solution is so obvious?

Answer (score 7):

Found out how to simulate the mouse click of an item. Posting it here in case someone else is trying to do this. It is actually quite simple. Use compute the coordinate to click and use QTest do the actual clicking.

```
void ClickItem( QQuickItem* pItem, QWindow* pRootWindow )
{
   auto oPointF = pItem->mapToScene( QPoint( 0, 0 ) );
   auto oPoint = oPointF.toPoint();
   oPoint.rx() += pItem->width() / 2;
   oPoint.ry() += pItem->height() / 2;
   QTest::mouseClick( pRootWindow, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier, oPoint );
 }
```

Comment: One question: how do you get the `QWindow`?

Comment: This worked also in my case. In my case the QWindow is from ```qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>( _qml.rootContext() )``` - where ```QQmlApplicationEngine _qml```